# Check if two instances of same class have same data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to validate if both my objects have the same values.

here's my class

```
public class myclass
{
    public List<c1> List1{ get; set; }
    public List<c2> List2{ get; set; }
    public List<c3> List3{ get; set; }
}

public class c1
{
    public int Number{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable{ get; set; }
}

public class c2
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Text{ get; set; }
    public GUID Guid{ get; set; }
}

public class c3
{
    public int? Age{ get; set; }
    public string Role{ get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted{ get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 instances of this class and I want to compare the data between both the instances and check if they both are the same or not.

I've tried Serializing both the objects and comparing but that's not working as the items in the list can be in a different order.

I've also tried getting HashSet of individual lists and checking if they are equal.

```
var s1 = new HashSet<c1>(list1);
var s2= new HashSet<c1>(list2);
return s1.SetEquals(s2);
```

Comment: First we need to decide the meaning of `same content`, specifically answer the question: in which case any given two objects of type c1 (c2/c3) are the same ? Do we compare them *by reference* or *by values*

Comment: @Fabjan compare by values. The idea here is to check if both the objects (which use the same class myclass) with the same class have the same values or not.

Comment: Since both of those classes have different property names, maybe just write a method which compares values of two properties?

Comment: @virouz98 no, both the objects are different instances of myclass. so they have the same baseclass.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to first order the lists using a standard order, like numeric or alphabetic depending on the types, and then trying something like this

```
if (myclassInstance1.list1.SequenceEqual(myclassInstance2.list1))
{
    //Repeat the cycle 2 more times and then //your code
}
```

Since this one works comparing the sequence you need to first order the lists and to do that you can maybe use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0)

**EDIT:** This is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0) for the list.sequenceEquals() method

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is if you explicitly implement the models with [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0#methods) in .NET.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public List<C1> C1List { get; set; }
        public List<C2> C2List { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class C1 : IEqualityComparer<C1>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        
        public bool Equals(C1 x, C1 y)
        {
            if(string.Equals(x.FirstName, y.FirstName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               && string.Equals(x.LastName, y.LastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(C1 c)
        {
            return c.FirstName.Length * c.LastName.Length;
        }
    }
    
    public class C2 : IEqualityComparer<C2>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        
        public bool Equals(C2 x, C2 y)
        {
            if(string.Equals(x.FirstName, y.FirstName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               && string.Equals(x.LastName, y.LastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(C2 c)
        {
            return c.FirstName.Length * c.LastName.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

The IEqualityComparer will give you full control on "**the parameters based on which you call 2 objects equal**".

As for the above implementation, I have considered the 2 objects are equal if the FirstName and the LastName are same.

Comment: Is there no other way I can compare the values other than explicitly implementing it? I've added a few properties as an example I have some 10-15 properties on each list. So, would it be wise to add all the properties to compare as mentioned above??

Comment: What do you mean by 10-15 properties on each list? List can have elements. Assuming, there are n properties in a class, is there any identifying logic that can define the equality constraints of 2 objects? You can write some logic to make that decision based on a composite key. E.g., for C2, Guid is a standard identifying field. For C1 and C3 there is no standard identifier. If you stress on the drill-down of the objects, you may also go for implementing prototype design pattern (**this is a complicated way**) OR you can restructure the model to group the data logically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to order the list,and then compare the data in it:

```
List<c1> l1 = list1.OrderBy(c => c.Number).ToList();
            List<c1> l2 = list2.OrderBy(c => c.Number).ToList();
            bool equalValue = true;
            if (l1.Count() == l2.Count()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count(); i++){
                    if (l1[i].IsAvailable != l2[i].IsAvailable || l1[i].Number != l2[i].Number || l1[i].Name != l2[i].Name)
                    {
                        equalValue = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                equalValue = false;
            }
return equalValue;
```